# Difference between /var/www/html directory and /www as root directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I was setting up a website on a web hosting service.

When I was transferring the files using ssh, I had to put the files in the www folder in my root directory (I would use cd www to get there), but when I was using AWS server in the previous occasion, I had to go to /var/www/html directory to put the files in and get the website running.

Are there any differences to these two formats? The website works fine, but I was just worried that there may be a pitfall or something!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine, different distributions of Linux have different default locations for the [DocumentRoot directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot), and on your hosting service the hosting company may have changed the location from the default.  But as long as you and the Apache process have read / write permissions on the root directory, you shouldn't 
have any problems.

Comment: Thanks gareth! So there shouldn't be any security issues right? I was planning on saving mysql login info in the main folder (the one before www) and was just wondering if it could be accidentally accessible!

Comment: I'd recommend making a subdirectory for the MySQL login data if it's sensitive, and lock down the permissions so that it's only readable by authorized users.